# Using Angular to Inject into non-Angular Objects

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Is there a way to provide a non-Angular injection target to the Angular $injector such that Angular constructs like $http, $scope, $location or $q can be injected into it?

```
//non-angular injection container
var injectionTarget= {
    $http:undefined,
    $scope:undefined
}

//means to inject into target - this is the part in question
var injector = angular.injector();
injector.injectInto( injectionTarget, ["$http", "$scope"]);
```

I'm having the hardest time finding any info on how to accomplish what I would assume is a very sought-after feature.

Comment: Have you found https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector ?

Comment: I did look at the docs, however it's rather cryptic and when trying their inline example, it kept throwing errors about finding certain associated injectionAsset + "Provider".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that probably the easiest way to do this would be to register your objects as services with the module.

```
var myObject = {} //Defined elsewhere or here as empty

app.service(‘aReferenceName’, function($http){
  myObject.$http = $http;
  return myObject;
});
```

This would have the double effect of setting the properties you want on your object, and making it accessible from angular as needed. It's also a pretty simple block of code. Note the implication though that as a service it would be a singleton from angular's perspective. If you need to do it as a class with many instances, you'll be wanting a factory.

Comment: As an additional note, you don't need to define variables as undefined in JavaScript to prevent errors; it won't help.